# How to match p-value for slope in linear model in R from the t-statistic?

Tags: r, regression, hypothesis-testing

Why doesn't `pt(coef(s)[1, 3], 98) * 2` match the intercept p value in the following example?

```
set.seed(123)
x = rnorm(100)
y = rnorm(100)
l = lm(x~y)
s = summary(l)
pt(coef(s)[2, 3], 98) * 2 #matches y p-value
pt(coef(s)[1, 3], 98) * 2 #does not match intercept p-value
```

Comment: A p-value must be a probability, which means it *must* be between 0 and 1. If you calculate a probability greater than 1 you did it wrong. Try drawing a picture of the area you're calculating in each case. .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try these two:

```
2 * pt(q = abs(coef(s)[2, 3]), df = 98L, lower.tail = FALSE) #y p-value
2 * pt(q = abs(coef(s)[1, 3]), df = 98L, lower.tail = FALSE) #intercept p-value
```

See I added `lower.tail = FALSE` and also stripped the sign with `abs`. That's because we are testing the deviation from zero, therefore the sign isn't important.

Answer (score 2):

The test statistic is greater than 0. You must look at the inverse area using 1-the lower tail area or augment `pt` to give upper tail area.

Comment: can you provide a link or something to explain that

Comment: Debugging programming is off-topic for the site, but try `?pt`.